# Fastest way to check if a jQuery object has some DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery object with some DOM elements. I take this object and sort its elements. But some elements have priority, so when I sort, I can't let them under the ones which don't have priority.

Example:

```
<!-- original list -->
<el id='2' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='0' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='3' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='1' /> <!-- no priority -->
<el id='4' /> <!-- no priority -->

<!-- wrong way to sort -->
<el id='0' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='1' /> <!-- no priority -->
<el id='2' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='3' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='4' /> <!-- no priority -->

<!-- right way to sort -->
<el id='0' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='2' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='3' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='1' /> <!-- no priority -->
<el id='4' /> <!-- no priority -->
```

How I'm solving this:

```
var elements = $(selector);
elements.sort(sort_by_id);
var priority_elements = get_prio_elements(); //That's the only way to know which are the elements with priority
var temp = $();
elements.each(function(){
    if(priority_elements.is(this))  //check if element are inside priority list
        temp = temp.add($(this));  //push element in elements object order
});
set_prio_elements(temp);
```

My output should be `temp` object. I mean: `temp` should contain:

```
<el id='0' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='2' /> <!-- has priority -->
<el id='3' /> <!-- has priority -->
```

in this order.

The problem is that this code is very slow for large lists (more than 300 +-). I'd like to know how can I improve this.

[A link at fiddle that could help understand.](https://jsfiddle.net/jjppof/fhabgbz6/2/)

Comment: What does `sort_function` look like? You can order by priority and id in the same sort operation.

Comment: None of the code you've provided should be noticeably slow. Have you profiled it to see *exactly* what part of it is slow? It is the sorting via `sort_function`, or the retrieving of the priority elements via `get_prio_elements`?

Comment: The `each()` part is slow. And I can't use `"[priority='true']"` as a selector, Actualy, I have nothing that indicates the priority. I just can have access to what is the priority elements with the `get_prio_elements` function.

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing.

Comment: Create a working example so we can try to reproduce the "slowness".  Are you familiar with [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I'll build an working example.

Comment: I editted the question. Sorry for being confusing... I think I'm clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just check, in your sort_function, if the element has its 'priority' attribute set to 'true'?

I would first gather all your elements in 2 arrays : one for priority='true' and the other for the opposite, sort those arrays, then concatenate them.

---

**UPDATE:**
I created this fiddle, see if you can adapt it, if you like
And then see if it's more resource efficient.
I'm guessing it is, because you don't have to go through the whole 'elements' object again, but I may be wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/qev5r9yx/

What's changed:
1) We sort both objects

```
elements.sort(sort_by_id);
priority_elements.sort(sort_by_id);
```

2) We just place priority elements back at the start by deleting them then unshifting

```
  for( var i = elements.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
    var index = priority_elements.indexOf( elements[ i ] );
    if( index > -1 ) {
        var temp = elements[ i ];
        elements.splice( i , 1 );
      elements.unshift( temp );
      priority_elements.splice( index , 1 );
    }
  }
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> My output should be temp object. I mean: temp should contain:
>   `<el id='0' /> <!-- has priority -->`
>   `<el id='2' /> <!-- has priority -->`
>   `<el id='3' /> <!-- has priority -->`

Well then, why don't you just do

```
priority_elements.sort( sort_by_id );
```

?
Because basically, what you seem to be doing is getting the priority elements, then check in the original list if they have the priority, and if they do, just keep them...
But you already have them in the first place? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Actualy, I don't have access to the `priority` attr. I have access only to priority elements getting them by the `get_prio_elements()`

Comment: Why can't you access the attribute?

Comment: Because they don't exist. I put them just to make the problem clear, but I got backfired... I'm builnd an working example.

Comment: @Mr.Felix I've updated my answer. See what you can do with it :)

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to understand what your JS code is actually doing as you seem to have missed out several key functions.

That being said, you state that your desired output is to sort the elements first by their `priority` then by their `id`. You can do this in a single `sort()` call.

First note that creating your own attributes is invalid, so `priority` should be `data-priority`. From there you can implement your own `sort()` logic, something like this:

```
$(selector).sort(function(a, b) {
    var $a = $(a), 
        $b = $(b), 
        aId = parseInt(a.id, 10), 
        bId = parseInt(b.id, 10);

    // sort by priority
    if ($a.data('priority') && !$b.data('priority'))
        return -1;
    else if (!$a.data('priority') && $b.data('priority'))
        return 1;

    // sort by id
    if (aId < bId)
        return -1;
    else if (aId > bId)
        return 1

    return 0;
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/kzt8vp00)

Note that the above can be shortened a lot via the use of ternary expressions, but I kept it verbose so you can clearly see what's happening.

Comment: Actualy, I don't have access to the `priority` attr. I have access only to priority elements getting them by the `get_prio_elements()`